# failed to connect to Mesos browser message after successfully connecting

Tags: mesos

As you can see I can connect to Mesos through the browser at address:  http://ec2-35-180-230-169.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:5050/#/

But then after 2 seconds this screen pops up saying "Failed to connect to ec2-35-180-230-169.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:5050!"

Same problem on Safari and Firefox.

Here is state info:

```
"version":"1.7.2","build_date":"2019-04-29 16:49:35","build_time":1556556575.0,"build_user":"root","start_time":1561467923.587283,"elected_time":1561467923.5961607,"id":"c54f9020-25c2-4890-8072-37e591a2f1d6","pid":"master@172.31.47.43:5050","hostname":"paris2x","capabilities":["AGENT_UPDATE"],"activated_slaves":1.0,"deactivated_slaves":0.0,"unreachable_slaves":0.0,"leader":"master@172.31.47.43:5050","leader_info":{"id":"c54f9020-25c2-4890-8072-37e591a2f1d6","pid":"master@172.31.47.43:5050","port":5050,"hostname":"paris2x"},"flags":{"agent_ping_timeout":"15secs","agent_reregister_timeout":"10mins","allocation_interval":"1secs","allocator":"hierarchical","authenticate_agents":"false","authenticate_frameworks":"false","authenticate_http_frameworks":"false","authenticate_http_readonly":"false","authenticate_http_readwrite":"false","authentication_v0_timeout":"15secs","authenticators":"crammd5","authorizers":"local","filter_gpu_resources":"true","framework_sorter":"drf","help":"false","hostname_lookup":"true","http_authenticators":"basic","initialize_driver_logging":"true","ip":"172.31.47.43","log_auto_initialize":"true","logbufsecs":"0","logging_level":"INFO","max_agent_ping_timeouts":"5","max_completed_frameworks":"50","max_completed_tasks_per_framework":"1000","max_unreachable_tasks_per_framework":"1000","memory_profiling":"false","min_allocatable_resources":"cpus:0.01|mem:32","port":"5050","quiet":"false","recovery_agent_removal_limit":"100%","registry":"replicated_log","registry_fetch_timeout":"1mins","registry_gc_interval":"15mins","registry_max_agent_age":"2weeks","registry_max_agent_count":"102400","registry_store_timeout":"20secs","registry_strict":"false","require_agent_domain":"false","role_sorter":"drf","root_submissions":"true","version":"false","webui_dir":"/usr/share/mesos/mesos-1.7.2/build/../src/webui","work_dir":"/var/lib/mesos","zk_session_timeout":"10secs"},"slaves":[{"id":"f071d1c1-1e28-4d17-8ab1-306dfdd47e31-S0","hostname":"localhost","port":5051,"attributes":{},"pid":"slave(1)@127.0.0.1:5051","registered_time":1561467925.269364,"reregistered_time":1561467952.9056547,"resources":{"disk":74229.0,"mem":6958.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":2.0,"ports":"[31000-32000]"},"used_resources":{"disk":0.0,"mem":0.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":0.0},"offered_resources":{"disk":0.0,"mem":0.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":0.0},"reserved_resources":{},"unreserved_resources":{"disk":74229.0,"mem":6958.0,"gpus":0.0,"cpus":2.0,"ports":"[31000-32000]"},"active":true,"version":"1.7.2","capabilities":["MULTI_ROLE","HIERARCHICAL_ROLE","RESERVATION_REFINEMENT","RESOURCE_PROVIDER","RESIZE_VOLUME"]}],"recovered_slaves":[],"frameworks":[],"completed_frameworks":[],"orphan_tasks":[],"unregistered_frameworks":[]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesos UI uses `leader_info` from `state.json` endpoint to query the leader. First request goes to URL provided by user but then it tries to hit leader directly. In your example leader info is:

```
"leader_info":{
  "id":"c54f9020-25c2-4890-8072-37e591a2f1d6",
  "pid":"master@172.31.47.43:5050",
  "port":5050,
  "hostname":"paris2x"
},
```

and UI is trying to connect [`'//' + leader_info.hostname + ':' + leader_info.port`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/731e90e8adb0560221db4703b449282c3906914b/src/webui/app/controllers.js#L68) so in your case this will be `//paris2x:5050`.

To fix this error you need to change hostname of your master to something that will be accessible or put a facade in front of it.

Comment: I changed the startup to sudo ./mesos-master.sh --hostname=(public domain name) --ip=172.31.47.43 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos